# Por que é que a mensagem de boas vindas está em Inglês?

Tags: bug, status-intencional, tradução

Eu inscrevi-me no Stack Overflow em Português e recebi o seguinte e-mail:

> Bem-vindo a Stack Overflow em Português!
>
> Thanks for signing up for Stack Overflow em Português! Here are some things you can do to get started...
>
> Find out what makes us different from your typical forum by learning about features like voting, reputation, and privileges
>
> Ask a question, or browse unanswered questions and share your expertise!
>
> Have questions about your account or the site? Visit meta or contact us through the help center.
>
> This is a one-time email. Visit your profile to set your preferences for other types of emails from Stack Exchange.

## Por que é que esta mensagem está em Inglês?

Tenho a certeza que os utilizadores portugueses gostariam de receber o texto de introdução ao site em Português.

Comment: Well, the first sentence is in Portuguese =P  So technically they get "welcomed."

Comment: Why is the Spanish site not in beta as the Portuguese one? :'( Please let us know if you need help...

Comment: @yms Sites need to go through the Area 51 process. I am not aware of the spanish one. Did you take a look at the area 51 page ?

Comment: [It's been at 100% commitment phase for a few months now](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42810/stack-overflow-in-spanish), that`s why I am asking...

Comment: @yms Nice didn't know about it. Well chances are it is on the way.

Comment: Esta e a outra questão em inglês estão sendo discutidas no Metão: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214277/foreign-language-questions-shouldnt-be-migrated/214282#214282

Comment: @bigown foi mal entendi errado.

Answer (score 2):

Isso é de se esperar à medida que adicionamos mais funcionalidades ou enquanto *internacionalizamos* funcionalidades antigas.

Essas expressões ainda não foram traduzidas, pelo que o sistema usa a versão em Inglês. Nós normalmente temos uma "entrega" de expressões traduzidas a cada duas semanas, pelo que, o problema vai desaparecer em breve.

---

> This is to be expected as we add more features or while we internationalize old ones.
>
> Those sentences have not been translated yet so the system uses the English version. We usually have a "drop" of translated strings every couple of weeks, so the problem will go away shortly.