# Tradução de "migrada do Meta.SO"

Tags: debate, bug, localização

Podemos ver o erro [nesta pergunta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417/por-que-%C3%A9-que-a-mensagem-de-boas-vindas-est%C3%A1-em-ingl%C3%AAs). Parece que a frase que explica a migração tem três partes "veio de" + "meta site (*if true*)" + "descrição do site":

> **migrada** de meta.stackoverflow.com <sup><sub>30/12/13 às 17:05</sub></sup>
>
> <sup>Esta pergunta veio de nosso site de discussões, suporte e solicitações de recursos de professional and enthusiast programmers.</sup>

Quando a migração é aqui do site principal, a mensagem é:

> **migrada** de pt.stackoverflow.com <sup><sub>24/06 às 17:17</sub></sup>
>
> <sup>Esta pergunta veio de nosso site de programadores profissionais e entusiastas.</sup>

Pode ser que sejam somente duas partes, mas o que parece certo é que falta traduzir [a audiência/descrição do site](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/sites#filter=default&run=true) (é sempre igual para Meta e site Principal). E talvez não tenha necessidade de traduzir todas as audiências dos 100+ sites da rede, pois a maioria dos casos de migração externa provavelmente sejam Meta.SO e Meta.SE. A audiência do Meta.SO é a que aparece no erro acima e a do Meta.SE é:

> meta-discussion of the Stack Exchange family of Q&A websites

Comment: Não era preciso a referência ;) Ainda por cima fui preguiçoso para criar esta pergunta :P
[Ver na revisão](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/2023/1)